# Company delays interview outcome in order to interview more candidates

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, job-change

I've interviewed with a big firm in the software industry and the interview went well, they gave me a good feedback.

Once completed all the interview steps the manager said that I would get a response within a couple of weeks. By that day the feedback date has been delayed two times.

Everytime they say that I'm in the run and that I'm a strong candidate but they want to interview more people in order to find the best match.

How should I handle this situation considering that I'm receiving offers from other companies?

Comment: See also: [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/6018)

Answer (score 24):

### Entertain the other offers

The most important thing about job hunting is that words are free and until it's in writing, you only have empty promises.

If this job you're waiting on is something you really want and the offers you've received are much less desirable, it may be appropriate for your specific situation to wait. However, if you've been delayed several times for the company to find the 'best match' it may mean that you've heavy competition for that spot and it could easily go against you.

I recommend you reach out to the big firm and inform them that you have received offers that you need to respond to and ask them if they are likely to extend an offer to you within a week (or 2 weeks, whatever timeline works for you). Be cognizant of the other offers as well. If those work for you and you wish to compare your best option, you need to give them a response within a reasonable time frame.

If the big firm cannot provide an offer within your time frame, withdraw your application and focus on the offers in hand.

Bird in the hand is worth two in the bush situation.

Answer (score 11):

> How should I handle this situation considering that I'm receiving
>   offers from other companies?

If one of the other companies makes a good enough offer, accept it.

If you think the potential at this company is worth the risk, then reject the other offers and wait.

The fact that this company is delaying in order to interview more candidates likely means that you haven't impressed them enough to stop their process and hire you. You might still end up being the chosen candidate, but you might not.

The fact that you are getting other offers now probably means that you'll get other offers later, should this particular company fall through.

Answer (score 5):

> they want to interview more people in order to find the best match.

This means you are not the best match.  If you can find a job elsewhere, do it.